# How do I prevent "dekstop" css from downloading in Android Chrome on Nexus 4?

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, mobile, optimization

I'm writing a mobile-first website with progressive enhancement, so I've setup a base.css file that handles layout for small/mobile screens (704px or less) and a full.css file that handles layout for desktop/tablet screens.

This is how I link the files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css?v=1.67" media="screen, handheld">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/full.css?v=1.7" media="screen and (min-width:44em)">
```

(The 44em is 704px based on "base" font size of 16px, however as part of my debugging this problem I have used absolute pixel values instead, and quiet large ones at that, to no avail. Speaking of the problem...)

The problem I get is that my nexus 4 device downloads the full.css file. It is shown in the chrome inspector I setup using USB debugging and confirmed using wireshark. It even outputs a couple of warnings to the console, so full.css is definitely being processed.

Like mentioned above I even tried using large pixel values (1980px) but the phone still downloads the file. The really strange part is that the layout doesn't **look** like full.css is being used. In fact if I remove the media query so it loads "properly" it screws up the layout, as it should.
So basically the site behaves correctly but the bandwidth is still being used to download full.css, which is not ideal since I want to optimize the site as much as possible.

Is this a known issue with chrome for android? Is there any solutions (short of doing browser/resolution detection on the server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers download all stylesheets as the CSSOM currently has no way of managing a stylesheet that's included but not downloaded (this may be addressed via an attribute in the future)

Browsers are free to prioritise the order in which stylesheets are downloaded though - if you look at this waterfall for iOS Safari (http://www.webpagetest.org/result/130912_9Z_7d0e1737392e338ea206af78bd615c89/) then you'll see the download of the larger screen stylesheets are deferred until later in the waterfall.

I'd generally recommend merging all the stylesheets into one that contains the MQs within it, as they contain highly repetitive text that compresses well with GZIP. (there are some scenarios in which you might want to do this though)

Comment: *sigh* Too bad, but what can you do. Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: I'll ping one of the Chrome guys to see why the behaviour has changed

Comment: Perhaps someone who downvoted could explain what's wrong with the answer - is it missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "mobile first" stylesheet. Typically you create a stylesheet with media queries that default to desktop, then scale down to tablet, then to mobile devices.

The "mobile first" approach does the opposite. The default styles dictate how it looks on a mobile device, then you move to the tablet, then the desktop.

The idea behind this is that the tablet and desktop CSS won't load on the mobile device, and the styles are already mobile optimized.

I haven't read through the article but maybe try something like this for more information.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

Comment: That article is actually where I got the idea for doing it the way I am. While I can put the contents of full.css into base.css and just wrap it all up in a media query it doesn't actually fix my main issue - downloading all that content, which I don't need.

Comment: I would look into a lazy load script if this isn't meeting your requirements. Essentially it will do what dystroy suggested.